# Exception: “Missing key value on ‘Storyboard’ object.” with styled triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles

I'm restyling a button, and that includes providing a controlTemplate and also adding some triggers (for mouseenter and mouseleave).

My XAML is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Color  x:Key="ForeColour" R="128" G="128" B="128" A="255"/>

        <Color x:Key="BackColour" R="211" G="211" B="211" A="255"/>

        <Color x:Key="GlowColour" R="30" G="144" B="255" A="255"/>

        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ForeColour}" x:Key="ForeBrush"/>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackBrush" StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BackColour}"  Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Storyboard x:Name="mouseOverText">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Self}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" From="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ForeColour}" To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GlowColour}"/>
        </Storyboard>

    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ForeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="8" Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BackBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="cnpContent" Opacity="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource mouseOverText}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but when I run it I get the following error on startup:

```
'Missing key value on 'Storyboard' object.' Line number '88' and line position '31'.
```

Which corresponds to this line:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Self}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" From="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ForeColour}" To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GlowColour}"/>
```

All I'm trying to do is get the button's foreground to fade to a different colour when the mouse hovers over it. Anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong? I can't seem to fathom it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three issues.

One is that you are adding the Storyboard to a resource dictionary without specifying a key.  I think you want `x:Key` instead of `x:Name`.

The next is that by setting `Storyboard.Target` to a binding with `RelativeSource Self`, you're setting the target to the ColorAnimation itself.  You can actually just leave that attribute off and it will target the Button by default.

Finally, you have the TargetProperty set to `Foreground`, but you actually want to animate the Color property of the Foreground brush, so you need to use `Foreground.Color`.  Try this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="mouseOverText">
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
        From="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ForeColour}"
        To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GlowColour}"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, can't believe I missed those!