# WPF Error "Missing key value on object

Tags: xaml, exception, key, datatemplate

I am receiving the error in a xaml resource file on build. Here is the xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.Controls"
                    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Automation.Data;assembly=Automation"
                    xmlns:a="clr-namespace:Automation;assembly=Automation"  >
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkflowDropdownSetting">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <s:WorkflowDropdown x:Key="settingFlowList" />
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource settingFlowList}" Width="200" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnEditWorkflow" Command="{x:Static s:WorkflowUICommands.EditWorkflow}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DefaultValue}">Edit...</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is the source for WorkflowList.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Automation.Data;

namespace DiagramDesigner
{
    public class WorkflowList : ObservableCollection<Workflow>
    {
        public WorkflowList()
        {
            AutomationDataContext cntxt = Engine.Data;
            IEnumerable<Workflow> lst = Engine.Data.Workflows.AsEnumerable<Workflow>();

            foreach (Workflow flow in lst)
            {
                Add(flow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this object as a resource in another xaml (not a resource file) and it works fine:

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.WorkflowMain"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
     Title="WorkflowMain" SizeToContent="Width" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <ScrollViewer Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <s:WorkflowList x:Key="flows"/>
                <Brush x:Key="BrdrBrush">#D6FF9436</Brush>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PowderBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="Heading" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="bold"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="ColumnHeader" TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="bold"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
            Padding="4"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrdrBrush}"
            Background="AliceBlue"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Job"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Description"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstAction"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Button"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Workflows:" Style="{StaticResource Heading}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}">Name:</Label>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}">Name:</Label>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}">Description:</Label>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}">First Task:</Label>
                    </WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource flows}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PowderBlue"/>
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <Grid Background="AliceBlue"  Margin="0 0 0 5"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Job"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Name"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Description"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstAction"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Button"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Job.Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="3">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstAction.Name}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="4">
                                    <Button Name="editButton" Command="{x:Static s:WorkflowUICommands.EditWorkflow}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsDefault="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">Edit...</Button>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <Button Name="btnNewWorkflow" Command="{x:Static s:WorkflowUICommands.NewWorkflow}" >New Workflow...</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

When I build I see this error:

```
Error   5   Missing key value on 'WorkflowDropdown' object. C:\Source\Projects\devtest\UI\WorkflowUI\DiagramDesigner\Resources\SettingTemplates.xaml    7   2   DiagramDesigner
```

[The only question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507835/exception-missing-key-value-on-storyboard-object-with-styled-triggers) I could find regarding this error does not apply because I am using x:Key already.

The solution runs just fine, but the error is preventing the designer from being interactive. It displays fine until you try to interact with it and then it is disabled with the following exception listed at the top:

```
XamlObjectWriterException was thrown on "DataTemplate":Missing key value on 'WorkflowList' object. Click here to hide detail.

An Unhandled Exception has occurred
Missing key value on 'WorkflowList' object.
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.GetKeyFromInstance(Object instance, XamlType instanceType, IAddLineInfo lineInfo)
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentCollection(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I seem to just be spinning my wheels.

Comment: From the "Error 5" message, it seems that the error is on line 44 and you don't have 44 lines of code in the snippet above - is the code here abbreviated, or maybe you're not examining the actual file that is loaded?

Comment: The code is abbreviated. I've edited and posted the actual error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but can tell that the designer is very sensitive and unstable when it comes to custom-defined classes, attributes, etc. Especially when they lie in a sub-folder of the project.